# How do I get my AKS cluster to authenticate to my ACR?

Tags: azure, azure-aks, azure-container-registry

A few weeks ago, I was able to use the Azure CLI to create my Container Registry (ACR) and Kubernetes (AKS) cluster. I could push images to my ACR and have AKS pull images successfully - everything worked great. Every now and then, I would have to refresh my login with `az acr login --name <acrName>`, but not a big deal.

Today, I found that when I go to deploy an updated image to my AKS cluster, I got a status of `ImagePullBackOff`:

> Failed to pull image "MY_ACR.azurecr.io/MY_IMAGE:v1": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Error response from daemon: Get https://MY_ACR.azurecr.io/v2/MY_IMAGE/manifests/v1: unauthorized: authentication required, visit https://aka.ms/acr/authorization for more information.

I couldn't remember what I needed to do to make this work, so I went through my original steps and created an entirely new resource group, ACR, AKS cluster, and service principal connecting them. I pushed images to my ACR and was able to apply my Kubernetes manifest, and everything worked again.

A couple hours later, when I applied an updated manifest, I again got the same error message. As part of my setup, I created a service principal:

```bsh
az ad sp create-for-rbac --skip-assignment
az role assignment create --assignee <principal's appId> --scope <my ACR's id> --role Reader
```

I also used `--role acrpull`. It seems like the authentication has timed out, and the documentation for [Authenticate with an Azure container registry](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/container-registry-authentication) says that individual AD identities will time out after 3 hours, but even after running `az acr login --name <acrName>`, I'm not able to fix the issue.

What are the required steps to get my AKS cluster to be able to authenticate again to my ACR?

I'll note that I also attached the ACR according to the documentation at [Authenticate with Azure Container Registry from Azure Kubernetes Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/cluster-container-registry-integration#configure-acr-integration-for-existing-aks-clusters) by running:

```
az aks update -n cluster_name -g resource_group --attach-acr acr_name
```

I also tried using the ACR id instead of the name. After a minute or so, the command completed, and even a half hour+ later, I get the same permissions issue.

Comment: how are you linking your AKS to ACR ? are you using the `--attach-acr` argument for the az aks create command ?

Comment: I used `az aks update -n cluster_name -g resource_group --attach-acr acr_name` after the resources were already created.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to integrate AKS with ACR is to leverage the `--attach-acr` option during cluster creation. This will have AKS manage the service principal for your and handle the token refresh's

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/cluster-container-registry-integration#create-a-new-aks-cluster-with-acr-integration

Comment: I deleted my cluster and recreated using `az aks create -g my_resourcegroup --name <new_cluster_name> --node-count 1 --generate-ssh-keys --enable-vmss --enable-cluster-autoscaler --min-count 1 --max-count 5 --service-principal <my_service_principl_guid> --client-secret <my_secret> --attach-acr <my_acr>`. Deploying to that new cluster also gives the same error.

Comment: Can you not provide the service principal ? And let kubernetes manage one for you using the MSI feature

Comment: Omitting the `--service-principal <my_service_principl_guid> --client-secret <my_secret>` from the command in my previous comment doesn't change anything. Same error.

Comment: thanks, I'm very curious now, since this is basic AKS + ACR integration, I will give this a try and report back